# Name binding and language binding

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler-construction, programming-languages, language-binding, name-binding

[Name binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) and [language binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) are different concepts. But I wonder if they are related and how they differ? Especially interested in the relation part. For example, if language binding is implemented in terms of name binding?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

They share the term *binding* in their names, that's about all. Of course a language binding will bind some names, but so will any non-trivial computer program.

Comment: @Mitch: what do you mean? Should this have been a comment in your opinion?

Comment: well, it's only my opinion but the original question seems to be answerable from reading the wikik links in the OP.

Comment: @Mitch: vote to close if you must. I wasn't expecting the *Great answer* badge for this one ;)